# Learning sharepoint, can I setup a dev enviornment? Book recommendations?

Tags: sharepoint

I want to learn sharepoint, can someone give me a quick overview of the various core things to learn in sharepoint?  Is it a single installation of a product or does it have various components to it that have to be installed separately?

Is there a book that you could recommend that would be the idea first book?

Comment: You could start at Youtube. There are tons of good tutorials and webcasts available.

Comment: “Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it.” [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 2):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/aa905688) is great place with a lot of information about SharePoint development and [Inside Microsoft SharePoint 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff742318.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to develop custom solution (programming) the good books are:

SharePoint 2010 as a Development Platform http://www.apress.com/9781430227069

Designing Solutions for Microsoft SharePoint 2010 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff770300.aspx

And a good book about some SharePoint 2010 features - Real World SharePoint 2010 http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Real-World-SharePoint-2010-Indispensable-Experiences-from-22-MVPs.productCd-0470597135.html